# HTML Bootstrap Carousel Responsive Picture

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When using the carousel from Bootstrap shown below: The image will resize until it reaches the size of the natural picture size of the picture.

```
<article class='image_content_container'>
  <div id='image_content_id' class='carousel slide image' data-ride='carousel'>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#image_content_id" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#image_content_id" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#image_content_id" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#image_content_id" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active image_item">
        <img src="Images/A.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="item image_item">
        <img src="Images/B.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="item image_item">
        <img src="Images/C.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
      <div class="item image_item">
        <img src="Images/D.jpg" alt="Fourth slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#image_content_id" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#image_content_id" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

To make this more responsive, I've tried making all img's as class .image-item and setting width: 100%. The pictures still only resizes as long as it has not met it's natural size. Additionally, I've tried using  instead of just a  tag to see if I can replace the image file with a more appropriate file when screen grows. However, that didn't work either:

```
...
<div class="carousel-inner role='listbox'>
    <div class="item active image_item">
        <picture>
            <Sources media="(min-width: 400px)" srcset="A-Large_1x.jpg 1x, A-Large_2x.jpg 2x">
            <img src="A-Small_1x.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </picture>
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

In short summary, I'm trying to make this carousel responsive such that
1) Images will scale to be bigger than natural size if necessarily (screen enlarged considerably)
2) Images will be replaced with higher resolution picture (1x or 2x) if necessary
3) Different sizes of the same images will be shown depending on screen width of device (A-Small.jps, A-Medium.jpg, A-Large.jpg)

The carousel works but the images do not resize nor will they show the appropriate version of a image based on device screen width. Do you guys have any ideas how I might about resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap provides you with a great class called **img-responsive**. It will make any picture responsive. Just include the class to every `<img></img>` element. If you want to know more about this, make sure to check the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

```
   ....
   <div class="item image_item">
      <img src="Images/B.jpg" alt="Second slide" class="img-responsive">
   </div>
   ....
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who stumbles across this, the correct answer for getting the  element to work within the bootstrap carousel is the correct source below.

tldr; the `<Sources>` tag was being used incorrectly, it should be `<source>`

**The first answer was correct for making an image responsive.**

But, if you're like me and want to serve an optimized image in the bootstrap carousel supported by the visitors browser and browser size (ie. mobile vs desktop) then you'll need the following:

```
<picture>
    <source class="d-block w-100" media="(min-width: 768px;)" srcset="not-real.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source class="d-block w-100" srcset="not-real-2.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source class="d-block w-100" media="(min-width: 768px;)" srcset="not-real.jp2" type="image/jp2">
    <source class="d-block w-100" srcset="not-real-2.jp2" type="image/jp2">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="not-real.jpg">
</picture>
```

This will let the browser serve the optimized image based on the file type supported (webp for most, jp2000 for Safari, and the jpeg for IE8+ as the fail-safe in the `img` tag), and based on the screen size.